# I want to add a time and date column to a csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to add time and date row at the end of each entry in the csv file.
I am only able to add time and date at the end of the database not to each row

Powershell

```
import-csv C:\Users\system\Desktop\WindowsUpdate1.csv | 
  foreach-object {
    $row = $_
    $row | add-member NoteProperty "Time" (Get-Date -format t) 
    $row 
  }
```

I only get one column in regard to the date and time instead of getting it in every row.

Comment: try using a calculated property with `Select-Object`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that `Select-Object` with calculated properties would be a better solution, as @Lee_Dailey notes, your code looks fine and should successfully add a `.Time` property to _each_ input object (row).

Answer (score 2):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) commented, the easiest way is to use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with a calculated property:

```
$newCsv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\system\Desktop\WindowsUpdate1.csv' | 
    Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Time'; Expression = {(Get-Date -format s)}}

#output on screen
$newCsv

#output to new csv file
$newCsv | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\system\Desktop\WindowsUpdate2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>I have changed your date/time format from `(Get-Date -format t)` to `(Get-Date -format s)` in order to get a sortable date/time format because the title of the post asks for date AND time. See [Standard Date and Time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for more formats</sup>